# How does this formula for finding all permutations of an array work?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, permutation

I failed at trying to get all permutations of a given array. With an array, let's say [1,2 3], it should return [[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[2,1,3],[2,3,1],[3,1,2],[3,2,1]]. I couldn't get it to work with my solution so I gave up and I checked someone else's solution and can't understand how it works.

```
const permute = (nums) => {
    // Backtracking
    const used = new Set(); // Keep track of what we have used
    const path = []; // Current potiential answer array
    const res = []; // Result array to be returned
    
    const dfs = () => {
        // If path is same length as nums, we know we have an answer. Push it to res array
        if(path.length === nums.length) {
            res.push([...path]); // We use spread operator to clone since arrays are pass by reference
        }
        
        // Every DFS we loop all numbers
        for(let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            // We can skip these numbers if they have been used
            if(used.has(nums[i])) continue;
            
            // Add to our potienial answer array and make it used by adding to used set
            path.push(nums[i]);
            used.add(nums[i]);
            
            // After adding, we call DFS again. DFS will continue till we hit the base case above
            // Think of this as just continuing down a path till we have an answer
            dfs();
            
            // Once we pop out of DFS, we need to remove from path array and remove from used Set
            // This will let it be used later in further paths
            path.pop();
            used.delete(nums[i])
        }
        
    }
    
    // Start DFS
    // All variables are global, no need to pass in anything
    dfs();
    
    return res;
}
```

I don't understand how this function ever reaches the `path.pop()` line if `dfs()` is called before it. I also don't see how this loop would ever end.

Comment: well ... if dfs is executed (which is conditional), when it finishes running, it returns

Comment: Eventually, `dfs` will not call itself anymore. This happens when all numbers have been used and the loop keeps executing `continue`. And so it is guaranteed that `dfs` returns, and each pending loop can eventually progress into a next iteration.